# vue condition scroll to div (itself)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, bootstrap-vue

I want to ask, that is it possible to make an action on a div that **scrolls to itself when it appears**.

**Environment:** I use vue / bootstrap-vue in the client side, and I use [alerts](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/alert) to inform the user. I made a vue component for that, and if something happened dynamically change the *text*, *variant* and the *show* attributes, to appear the information. However many sites are too big, so I wonder that in scrolling up, every time, whether the *show* attribute of alert component changes to true.

- I found a pretty awesome component for scrolling ([vue-scrollto](https://rigor789.github.io/vue-scrollto/#/examples))
  but it is not for this problem.
- I thought I made a watch on the show element and run this:       `scroll(0,0);` but it was not so smooth, and it always go to the top, not to itself.

What do you recommend me?

Comment: To clarify: 1. you have a component.  2.  When that component is rendered on the screen, you want the window to scroll to the location of the component.  Is that correct?

Comment: @MattMorgan Thx the comment. Exactly that I want.

Comment: If you want to scroll to an element you need to get its position. This is not possible in javascript when the element is invisible as far as I know. What can happen is that when you try to get the position of the element to scroll to it might still be hidden and therefore returning a position of `0,0`; remember it takes some time for the DOM to re-render and show the element again. A possible solution is to set a timeout and ask for the position later, like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o9pbs7et/1/

Comment: I liked this idea, and its working. If you write this as an answer I accept that as an answer! :)

Comment: @atlazor I forgot to tag you